# Android Samsung S2 spannablestringbuilder error

Tags: android

I'm working on an app which fetches data from server using `JSON`. It is working fine in emulator but in my phone, it is giving error and not getting data.

The error comes at this point in `JSON` Parser....

> HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);            httpPost.setEntity(new
>   UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));            HttpResponse httpResponse =
>   httpClient.execute(httpPost);//Error Point            httpEntity =
>   httpResponse.getEntity();

On the third line logcat shows....

> SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

I have searched a lot but it doesn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

check your string.lenght() it should not  0 .

Comment: The parameters for Post request and URL are all right.But when it gets response then it gives this error and throughs IOException.But in emulator it is fine and giving correct response.